# Radio buttons with vue 3 can select all of the options

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I find it odd that the radio buttons I clicked on selects all of the items in the list. I have tried to removed the checked property but still it doesn't work. I'm expecting it to work as a normal radio button but can't seem to make it work in Vue3 since I'm from Vue2 migrating it.

This is the Parent Component.

```
RadioButton.vue
<template>
      <TestRadioButton
        v-for="item in field.model.items"
        :key="item.itemId"
        v-model:value="value"
        :input-value="item.value"
        :name="field.valueField.name"
        :id="item.itemId"
        :title="item.text"
        :disabled="!isEnabled"
        :class="field.model.cssClass"
        @change="onInput($event.target.value)"
        @focus="field.tracker.onFocusField(field, value)"
        @blur="field.tracker.onBlurField(field, value, errors.value)"
        :error-message="errors.value.join(',')"
      />
</template>

<script>
import BaseField from './BaseField.vue';
import TestRadioButton from './TestRadioButton.vue';

export default {
  name: 'RadioButtonList',
  extends: BaseField,
  components: {
    TestRadioButton ,
  },
  beforeMount() {
    if (Array.isArray(this.field.value)) {
      this.value = this.field.value.join('');
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

```
TestRadioButton.vue

<template>
  <TestRadioButtonBase
    :checked="shouldBeChecked"
    type="radio"
    :input-value="inputValue"
    :title="title"
    :id="id"
    :name="name"
    :class="$style.radio"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    @updateInput="updateInput"
  />
</template>

<script>
import TestRadioButtonBase from './TestRadioButtonBase.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    TestRadioButtonBase,
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Number],
      required: true,
    },
    inputValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:value'],
  computed: {
    shouldBeChecked() {
      return this.value === this.inputValue;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      this.$emit('update:value', event.target.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
TestRadioButtonBase.vue

<template>
  <div :class="$style['form-item']">
    <input
      :id="id"
      :value="inputValue"
      @change="updateInput"
      :type="type"
      class="input"
      :class="$style.input"
    />
    <label class="label" :for="id" :class="$style.label" v-html="title" />
    <span v-if="optionalField" :class="$style['optional-field']">{{
      optionalField
    }}</span>

    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "checkbox",
    },
    inputValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    checkboxList: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      this.$emit("updateInput", event);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    optionalField() {
      return !this.required && this.type === "checkbox" && !this.checkboxList
        ? 'Optional'
        : null;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the extended vue component

```
BaseField.vue

export default {
...code

methods: {
 onInput(value) {
  this.value = value;
 }
}
```

]
[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqxpN.png)

Comment: [Radio buttons need to be grouped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group).  Try just adding `name="someName"` to the `input` element.